# Proving f cannot be convex

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

The following question I encountered in a convex optimization course and I can't seem to understand the solution.

[image: question]
[image: solution provided]

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: Is it visible now?

Comment: It's visible, but the image size is big.

Comment: Okay sorry.. I had to take it off my mobile. Anyways, kindly help me out if possible :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer provided means that when the function is restricted to the line (I) it is not convex. So the function $f$ is not convex.

Answer (score 0):

from the picture of level set, it shows function looks like the shape of $x^2 + y^2$, so it is convex (downward)

Comment: The answer to this question is f cannot be convex. Kindly look at the images posted

Comment: Using information you provided, it is a convex, or quasi-convex. Which one professor considers a the best answer.

Comment: Sorry, but that answer is wrong. You cannot simple assume that function as x^2 + y^2 and jump to conclusions

Comment: Proof has been provided as to why function cannot be convex. Disprove it before posting contradicting answers which makes such assumptions :)

Comment: You are shaking up my math understanding. Please ask professor for the explanation instead.

Comment: The basis of the explanation provided is the function must be convex when restricted to any line segment in its domain